# Crushing a central dividing circle in $\Sigma_2$ to a point

Tags: algebraic-topology

Crushing a central separating circle in $\Sigma_2$ to a point

So presentation of $\Sigma_2$ is $<x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2:[x_1,y_1][x_2,y_2]>$.

I understand that crushing this separating circle to a point will turn the space into a wedge of two tori and so the fundamental group will be $Z \oplus Z*Z \oplus Z$, but I was hoping somebody could explain to me, in terms of the group presentation, how this comes about. How does collapsing the separating circle destroy change the presentation to

$\Sigma_2 = < x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2: [x_1,y_1]=1, [x_2,y_2]=1>$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crushing the central circle to a point is of course homotopy equivalent to gluing a disk with that circle as boundary.  Since that circle is $[x_1,y_1]$, you have
$$
\langle x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2\mid [x_1,y_1][x_2,y_2],[x_1,y_1]\rangle
=\langle x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2\mid [x_1,y_1],[x_2,y_2]\rangle
$$

Comment: Hmm, i'm trying to understand why that circle is $[x_1,y_1]$... If it is $[x_1,y_1]$ then it must also be $[x_2,y_2]$

Comment: @MathematicalMushroom It is probably easiest if you view $\Sigma_2$ as the connected sum $T^2\#T^2$.  In $T^2=[0,1]^2/\sim$ you can see by enlarging the small disk at the middle, that it is $[x_1,y_1]$.